# How to target an element when navigating to another page (partial)

Tags: angularjs

I have a checkbox that I'd like to set the indeterminate state to based on the states of other checkboxes. When I'm on the page that the checkboxes are all in, it updates as expected (i.e. the checkbox is found). But when I navigate to that from another page, my method does not find the checkbox (i.e. returns `null`).

When I debug in Chrome devtools, I notice

```
let checkBoxWithIndeterminateState;
let checkbox = false;

fireWhenCheckBoxChanged() {
     // returns null when navigating from another page but not when on its own page
     checkBoxWithIndeterminateState = document.getElementById('checkBoxWithIndeterminateState')
     checkBoxWithIndeterminateState.indeterminate = true
}
```

Template:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkBoxWithIndeterminateState" data-ng-model="checkbox">
```

How do I wait until the new template has loaded before my method tries to find the checkbox? I've read some suggestions to use `this._$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded'...` but this doesn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What about adding an `ng-init` directive to your target checkbox and do your logic in it, this way you are sure the element is there, here is a suggestion:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-init="initTragetCheckbox()">
```

In your controller

```
$scope.initTragetCheckbox = function () {
    // your code to execute for other checkboxes
    var checkbox1 = document.getElementById("checkbox1");
    var checkbox2 = document.getElementById("checkbox2");
    ....
}
```